# copy existing linearLayout to a runtime alertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have a maintenance application, where the operator does a checklist, and the previous steps are disabled, but I need to be able to go back to the previous step, and I would like to do this in an alertDialog

I created a setOnLongClickListener and I'm getting the View, and trying to add in alertDialog, but I get the exception that the layout has a parent (), when I remove View with, removeView (), it works, but I can't remove the View of princiapal activity

```java
passo1.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
        dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(initManutencao.this);
        if (v.getParent() != null){
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);
        }
        dialogBuilder.setView(v);
        alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
        alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        alertDialog.show();
        //disableItens.ShowItensScren(0, initManutencao.this);
        return false;
    });
```

In short, I need to copy a LinearLayout with all its contents to an alertDialog, without me removing it from the main activity when I press it.

[Main Activity, should not be changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiqvV.jpg)
[wanted but without removing LinearLayout from the main activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uOKV.jpg)

Comment: I would recommend you approach this differently - instead of attempting to "lift" views and their data, inflate the dialog with its own view (even if it's identical), and copy the necessary data from the parent views onto the dialog.

Comment: but then I would have to create 10 different layouts for each situation